# GBrank: what is the final model?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ranking

A colleague and I cannot reach a consensus in what the GBrank model (after training) should look like.

**Introduction**

The method starts by performing the typical conversion from pairwise to a pointwise dataset, where the target variable *z* represents now a score which should be higher, *z<sub>i</sub> > z<sub>j</sub>* when *i* is preferred over *j*. The authors then suggest using Gradient Boosting Trees, and "punish" cases where that model is predicting *z<sub>j</sub> > z<sub>j</sub>* and *i* is preferred over *j*. The "punishment" is performed by switching the scores and also incrementing or decrementing by τ.

**Disagreement**

Where we disagree is whether Gradient Boosting Rank is itself an ensembler. That is, is the model we are training *g<sub>k</sub>* or is it *h<sub>k</sub>*?

**Reference Material**

- The original article: http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~zha/papers/fp086-zheng.pdf

[image: GBrank training algorithm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*h* is used in the whole paper to denote the hypothesis you are working with, *g* is just a domain specific regression model used to construct *h*, thus GBRank is *h<sub>k</sub>*. In particular, it is a boosting method, thus it has to be an ensemble, trained by building a strong learner from set of weak learners (from definition of boosting posed by Kearns and Valiant in late '80) - *h* is an ensemble (due to recurrent definition), *g* is not (as it is just a regressor trained on some transformed dataset).

Comment: Thank you, that was my interpretation and I found one implementation on the Internet as you say. Isn't it a bit strange though that the initial guess h_0 has such a big impact in the result? (AFAIK eta is a small value such as 0.05)

Comment: so when they say in step 2 "fitting a regression function using GBT" this is misleading/incorrect, it's actually the entire ensemble that is GBT?